# if statement executes before its conditional variables are set

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I have an `if` statement that's condition is passed to this implementation file via `NSUserDefaults` as seen below.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *code = [defaults objectForKey:@"codeKey"];
selectedCodeLocal = code;
```

After this code to retrieve the string variable, I have an if statement:

```
if (selectedCodeLocal == @"1")
    textView.text = "@blah blah blah";
else
    textview.text = "@abcdefghijklmnop";
```

When I build and run, it appears that the variable IS being passed, but it's not being passed until AFTER the `if` statement executes.

I have places `NSLog`'s around this code that return my `selectedCodeLocal` string variable and the variable's value is always one step behind. (For instance if I first pass it as 4, then pass it as 1, it will be returned in the log first as 1, then as 4, then as 1) Sorry if I've confused you with that.

UPDATE:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];
selectedCodeLocal = [defaults objectForKey:@"codeKey"];
NSLog(@"set: %@",selectedCodeLocal);

self.navigationItem.title = selectedCodeLocal;

[textView setClipsToBounds:NO];
[textView setEditable:NO];
[textView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 50, 50)];

if ([selectedCodeLocal isEqualToString:@"100"])
    textView.text = @"abc";
else
    textView.text = @"xyz";

}
```

The NSLog still displays the old value of `selectedCodeLocal`.

UPDATE: Here's where that Key is set. (in the previous View)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//Get the selected code

NSString *selectedCode = nil;

if(searching)
    selectedCode = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else {

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"codesKey"];
    selectedCode = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:selectedCode forKey:@"codeKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

}
```

@Firoze Lafeer: Does this answer your question?
[image: storyboard]

Comment: I've changed the code to this:
`NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`
`selectedCodeLocal = [defaults objectForKey:@"codeKey"];`
`[defaults synchronize];`
`NSLog(@"set: %@",selectedCodeLocal);`
The log file is still showing that my `selectedCodeLocal` string variable has not been updated until the next time this piece of code is run. (it's always 1 step behind)

Comment: [defaults syncrhonize] should be above selectedCodeLocal

Comment: It's still one step behind ;\  I placed `[defaults synchronize]` before `selectedCodeLocal = [defaults objectForKey:@"codeKey"];` and after `NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

Comment: where do you set the value? do the syncrhonize after you set the value, see the example on my answer

Comment: the value is set here: `selectedCodeLocal = [defaults objectForKey:@"codeKey"];` you told me to move the sync up above it. I can confirm that it does not work with the sync both above or below that line.

Comment: no, I meant, where do the value stored in NSUSerDefaults get set, [defaults setObject:@"4" forKey:@"codeKey"] is setting, [defaults objectForKey:@"codeKey"] is retrieving

Comment: @Paul, are you using a storyboard? How are you presenting this view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a storyboard, and a segue attached to a tableview cell, your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will be called **after** the new view controller is loaded and pushed.

So in other words, you are *setting* this key in your user's defaults after you have already *read* the value.

The right time to set up any data you need for the detail view controller is in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method on your tableview controller. `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is too late if you are using a segue on a tableview in a storyboard.

Other thoughts:

- Everyone else is right that you should be using `isEqualToString:`, not `==`. The fact that the latter is working for you is really an accident of implementation. You **need** to do the right thing and not depend on that. Using '==' (which is pointer comparison in this case) is wrong.
- Speaking of doing the right thing, you should consider if `selectedCode` really belongs in your user's preferences (NSUserDefaults). It would be much cleaner to just make that a @property of the detail view controller and set that property directly in your `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, you've opened my eyes to much since I've read this response. If I could accept it twice I would.

Comment: Oh, I'm glad that helped. Good luck with the app!

Answer (score 2):

when you change the value in the NSUserDefaults, do synchronize. For example

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:@"4" forKey:@"codeKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

also

```
if (selectedCodeLocal == @"1")
```

should really be

```
if (selectedCodeLocal isEqual:@"1")
```

Comment: the if statement works fine, thanks. But the `NSUserDefaults` still doesn't seem to set the string variable `selectedCodeLocal` in time.

Comment: one quick question, if you're manipulating it directly, why do you need to use NSUSerDefaults? At the moment, I don't see anything wrong with the code, maybe if you can post more code

Comment: I am passing a string from another view, thats why I am using `NSUserDefaults`. That string will determine (via an if statement) how to set a UITextView's text property in this new `View`

Comment: I'd show the full `viewDidLoad` method, but I'm not sure how to properly format the code in this comment box.

Comment: just edit your post for the question with more code if you want to

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that old favourite, string comparison.

I think you mean:

```
 if ([selectedCodeLocal isEqualToString:@"1"])
```

or something like it (it's been over a year since I've written Obj-C).

Comment: this seems like a better way to write an if statement's condition although both `==` and `isEqualToString:` work, but it still doesn't solve my problem of the variable not being set in time.  Any other ideas?

Comment: `isEqualToString:` is not a 'better' way to write an if statement. It is the right way. The equality operator, `==`, will test to see if two pointers point to the same object. This will rarely be the case when working with strings. The method `isEqualToString:` actually compares the *contents* of the pointers, which is want you, in most cases, probably want to do.